# How can I make a webcam stream with JavaScript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create a webcam stream, how I start my webcam on the admin page and insert a widget into the FrontEnd which is load the stream which is streamed from the admin site.

I solved how view the webcam on the admin page and how to load a video on the FrontEnd.

So how can I send the webcamera image continously and save it on the server temporarly, how only the last few seconds of the video is stored ( this last one is not important ) and load it on the FrontEnd?

Comment: You need to really refine this question - there's too many possible answers to the different questions

Comment: If I were you I would look for a solution with node.js and web sockets instead of php and plain javascript..

Comment: Thanks for the advice with the web sockets. I will learn a bit about these and then I will use this with PHP, because my CMS is written in PHP.